# How can I prove that $\int_X\left(\int_Y f_xdm_2\right)dm_1$ exists given the following conditions ...?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=Y=[0,1)$ and $f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{(1-xy)^a}$, where $a>0$, and $m_1=m_2$ the Lebesgue measure.

I want to prove that $$\displaystyle\int_X\left(\int_Y f_xdm_2\right)dm_1$$

exists (the integral is $<+\infty$) or it doesn't.

We fix $x\in X$. Then:

$$\int_Y f_xdm_2=\int_0^1\dfrac{dy}{(1-xy)^a}=-\dfrac{1}{x(-a+1)}{[(1-x)^{-a+1}}-1]=\dfrac{1}{x(a-1)}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{a-1}}-1\right).$$

Then $$\displaystyle\int_X\left(\int_Y f_xdm_2\right)dm_1=\int_0^1\dfrac{1}{x(a-1)}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{a-1}}-1\right)dx.$$

Did I do something wrong? I don't think this is easy to solve.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to expect that the anwser will depend on $a.$ You have a little problem with your answer when $a=1.$ Treat that case separately (it converges). For $a>0,a\ne 1,$ what you did is fine. You arrive at a one-variable integral where the integrand appears to have two singularities, at $0$ and $1.$ But the singularity at $0$ is removable. At $1,$ the integrand stays nice and bounded if $a<1.$ If $a>1,$ then the integrand blows up, being on the order of $1/(1-x)^{a-1}.$ For which $a>1$ does $\int_0^1 dx/(1-x)^{a-1}$ converge?

Here's something to observe that lends the problem some intuition: The integrand in the original double integral has a singularity at $(1,1).$ Consider the square $(1-\epsilon,1)\times (1-\epsilon,1)$ for small $\epsilon.$ The integrand on that square is $\ge 1/(1-(1-\epsilon)^2)^a \ge 1/(2\epsilon)^a.$ So the integral over that square is $> \epsilon^2/(2\epsilon)^a.$ Now if the integral was finite, that expression $\to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$ But notice that doesn't happen when $a\ge 2.$ That's actually a proof of divergence for $a\ge 0.$ See how that checks out with your Fubini method.

Comment: Thank you. I liked the way you see it in your second point.